# Symfony 1.4 doctrine admin generator display i18n form fields

Tags: internationalization, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, admin-generator

My problem is that iam using admin generator for model with some extra virtual attributes which i need to have in generator.yml definitions:

```
config:
  form:
    display: [name, design_by, description, _images, add_image, _videos, add_video]
```

But the "description" attribute is in i18n mode of doctrine model s it does'nt exists in core model object anymore - moved into i18n model.
So iam getting logical error 'Widget "description" does not exist'.

I tryed somthing like:

```
config:
  form:
    display: [description_i18n]
```

but did'nt found solution.

When i cut the form display definition into default, form starts working, but it miss my extra fields _images, add_image, _videos, add_video, so i need to have the definition there.

Google doesnt helped too...

Does anybody know how to define i18n widgets into generator.yml?
THX!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Diving into the code, I saw that the i18n widgets are grouped into arrays where key are the culture name.

So I tried to set them into my generator.yml:

```
form:
  display:
    'Name / Description (with translations)': [en, es, fr, it]
```

And succes!!!

Comment: I had to split my other fields into separate blocks like "main": [name, design_by], your yml bellow it and then block "data" with the rest, but this realy works.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before and I am not sure if this is the answer you are looking for but in order for Symfony to display i18n fields in the admin generator you need to add a line to each Form class in your project/lib folder.

For instance if you have a Form class in: `<myproject>/lib/form/doctrine/MyForm.class.php`

Add this to the configure method like so:

```
  public function configure()
  {
    parent::configure();

    // Add this line.
    $this->embedI18n(array('en', 'de'));
    ...
  }
```

Change en and de to the languages you have set up. You need to do this for every form object you have.

Comment: Read last line of my question again

Comment: Well I tied. And I have never heard of an i18n widget. Good luck.

Comment: BTW. resolved my problem by letting default (~) generator.yml setting and setting extrawidgets for my special attributes in form class, but it's not solution of this problem, so i'll let it open. THX for your answer anyway!